# How do I merge my onViewCreated into onCreateView that contains both layout fragment and Viewpager

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, oncreate

I had a viewPager that contained three tabs, namely Chat Rooms, Secret Chats and Chat Requests. But as you can see, I don't want secret chats and request for now on the app so i have removed those tabs from the xml and the chat activity.kt (Kotlin) and I have only chat rooms present as you can see in this activity code below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =// Inflate the layout for this fragment
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false)

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewpager)
    setupViewPager(viewPager)
}

private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
    val adapter = ChatAdapter(fragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(ChatRoomsFragment(), "Chat Rooms")
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
}
```

Now, when I open the chat, only chat rooms tab show. That's cool, but when I move around the app and return to the chat tab, the chatroom layout disappear and leave a blank screen. I believe this is because the tab is still setup by the viewPager which still expects to scroll through three tabs or/and because I have the viewPager in the onViewCreated which means whenever the process gets to it again, it wants to show the removed tabs?

I think merging the viewPager with the onCreateView might solve my problem but I don't know exactly how. I also think that tweaking the viewPager class or activity somewhere might help but again I don't know how to go about it.

To be clear what i want after this long explanation, I want to eliminate onViewCreated process and merge what that process was supposed to do with onCreateView process. If there is a way i can add all two processes directly into onCreate itslef or superOnCreate, that's fine too. Please help and forgive if fail community guidelines.

Below was the xml and kt activity i removed that housed the other two tabs.

```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/theme_primary"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

```
The activity under oncreate view at ChatFragment.kt
```

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.viewpager)
            setupViewPager(viewPager)
            val tabs = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs)
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        }

     private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager) {
            val adapter = ChatAdapter(fragmentManager)
            adapter.addFragment(ChatRoomsFragment(), "Chat Rooms")
            adapter.addFragment(PrivateChatFragment(), "Secret Chat")
            adapter.addFragment(RequestFragment(), "Chat Requests")
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
        }
```

Thanks is anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by transferring the methods in the chat room fragment kt onto chat fragments kt since chat fragment was the activity hosting all the tabs when I had three tabs. Now, it's hosting only chat rooms tab so, it is right that the chat rooms fragment activity methods be almost the same as chat fragment activity methods.